# Spring/JUnit - running Unit Tests that aren't really "tests"

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, gradle, junit

This question is more of a best practices approach.  The application we have is Spring Boot 1.5.4 and builds using Gradle.  I'm in the process of creating nightly builds with Jenkins, and want to make sure all the unit tests pass in the project.

The project has a number of "tests" like this however:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {Application.class})
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class DatabaseCreationProcessImplTest {
```

This particular class creates a sample database image for developers to work off of.  Granted we could make straight SQL scripts, but a Java process is useful since there's code that also queries for data from outside sources (e.g. Liferay.)

The reason we're using a unit test for this is because developers can easily run it in IntelliJ to load a new database image.  However this isn't really a "test", it's using the test runner as a quick way to run a Java process.

I'm working on setting up nightly builds and I don't want this test to be included in the builds.  I can do something like the following in the build script:

```
test {
exclude 'com/mydomain/service/util/impl/DatabaseCreationProcessImplTest.class'
}
```

However by doing this, if running the unit test individually in the IDE with the Spring test runner, it is unable to find any tests.  I thought about passing in a Boolean value in the Jenkins task for doing this, e.g.

```
test {
    systemProperties 'property': 'value'
    testLogging {
        events "passed", "skipped", "failed", "standardOut", "standardError"
    }

    // Exclusions go here
    if (Boolean.getBoolean('exclude.tests')) {
        exclude 'com/mydomain/service/util/impl/DatabaseCreationProcessImplTest.class'
    }
}
```

However this seems like a hack/kludge...  any ways looking for some "best practices" approach for handling this.  Is JUnit the right way for quickly running Java processes?  Are there other alternatives?  Is it possible to create a Gradle script which developers can use to invoke common Java (Spring Boot) process as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could group your not-really-tests in a test suite with JUnit's [@SuiteClasses](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runners/Suite.SuiteClasses.html) annotation:

```
@Suite.SuiteClasses(DatabaseCreationProcessImplTest.class)
public class NotReallyTests {}
```

And then use a condition that you pass from your Jenkins command line to exclude the not-really-tests suite:

```
test {
    if (project.hasProperty('excludeNotReallyTests')) {
        useJunit {
            excludeCategories 'fully.qualified.name.of.your.NotReallyTests'
        }
    }
}
```

Your Jenkins command line would then be

```
$ gradle -PexcludeNotReallyTests=true
```

It's a little less hacky than your solution in that it keeps track of the grouping of tests that are not really tests in the codebase instead of the `build.gradle` file.

Comment: I'm going to give this a try tonight.  The biggest challenge I'm facing is when developers run the "build" or "tests" tasks locally, I want these particular unit tests to be excluded.  If this approach will let me run tasks individually it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The Testing API for Android provides several annotations that are used to group tests together. Then you can specify which tests to run by giving one of the annotations on the command line. I do not know the details of how to implement this. It is just a suggestion for you to explore on your own, if you are interested.